# Limit the file inputs cloned in a form with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, clone, field

i use this Jquery function to clone the file input fields in my form,

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#clone');
    var i = $('#clone p').size() + 1;

    $('#addImg').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="attach"><input type="file" name="attachment_'+ i +'"  /> <a href="#" id="remImg">Remove</a></label></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remImg').live('click', function() {
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
});
```

is it possible to limit the fields that can be cloned? lets say a number of 4 fields?

thanks a lot,
Philip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use for example this first inside the function that adds an input:

```
if($('input[name^="attachment_"]').length>=4){return false;}
```

It counts the input's with a name-attribute that starts with `attachment_` and leaves the function if 4 are found.

Furthermore: you shouldn't use IDs for the elements that you clone, because IDs have to be unique, what they are not in this case. Use other attributes like `class` or `name`.

Comment: thanks a lot @Dr.Molle, this is working perfect and you are right about the ID's, i use the remImg as a class now.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to the answer from Dr.Molle...check/limit the amount of the input fields on the server side. Because JS can be manipulated on the client side..

Answer (score 0):

To really handle it correctly, you need something else, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#addImg').live('click', function(e) {
       for(var i=1; i<5; i++) { 
         if ($('#clone input[name="attachment_'+i+'"]').length == 0) break;
         if(i == 4) return false;
       }
       $('<p><label><input type="file" name="attachment_'+ i +'"  /> <a href="#" class="remImg">Remove</a></label></p>').appendTo('#clone');
       e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#clone').delegate('.remImg', 'click', function(e) {
       if($('#clone input[name^="attachment_"]').length > 1) {
          $(this).closest('p').remove();
       }
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[You can test it out (seeing the generated HTML/nodes) here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/cMyXF/).

What this does it loop through and finds the first available `i` to use.  Your original code *assumes* the last one is always the one removed, this may not be the case, and you'd still have a number repeated.  Instead this loops though, gets the first available index and uses that...if we get to `4` and they were all in use, abort (you could add an `alert()` or something in that `if` as well, if you wanted).

Also note the use of a class for `remImg` since it's repeated, and the use of [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to be a bit more efficient...you can also probably use just a normal [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler on `#addImg`, but I'm not 100% sure of it's location here.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nick Craver, your code works great but i have to keep the possibility to remove the last input. I have understand a lot from your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Philip - you can easily do that with my above code, just take away the `if()` check in the last event handler, like this:  http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/cMyXF/1/  Note that your accepted answer **will** have errors if any files are removed/added out of order.

Comment: i try your code but the delete button it's not working,
i see at your example that is working, i'm missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: @Philip - do you have a link to your page where it's not working?  Make sure you're using a *class* and not an *id* like I have in the code above...this makes valid HTML, whereas a repeated ID does not.